# What does it mean to "cut code"?

Tags: united-kingdom, job-description

I was looking at a [job offer](https://www.linkedin.com/jobs2/view/13712307):

> [...]
> I am looking for a Developer who hacks code for pleasure, takes pride
> in their works and displays a keen interest in learning new
> technologies (boys toys). My client doesn’t care what language you use
> they pick the best tools for the job. Day to day work will be highly
> varied and across the entire stack.
>
> The Java / Scala / Ruby
> developer will:
>
> - **Cut code** (a big surprise to many)
> - Release Management
> - Core software Development
>
> [...]

What does it mean to "cut code"? And why would that be a *big surprise*?

*Edit*: as I can read from the comments, it looks like being quite a negative term, so why would they employ it in a job offer?

Comment: Weird. I've been a developer since 1987 and that is literally the first time I've ever seen that term.

Comment: You had a job advertisement that actually says boys toys? How disgusting. As a woman I would never work for these jerks. I would guess cut code means that refactoring and shortening the total lines of code is encouraged. Since it isn't most places that is why it would be a surprise.

Comment: Honestly it just sounds like a non-technical person trying to be *hip* without knowing what it is they are really talking about.

Comment: http://linuxmednews.com/1173061242

Comment: @HLGEM +1 on the sexist tone of that ad. I'm a man and I wouldn't want to work for those jerks either.

Comment: http://www.quant-capital.co.uk/jobs/java-ruby-python-developer/ -  "Our client is an established financial data technology start up." what an oxymoron.

Comment: @HLGEM Removing code (_refactoring_) was my first thought as well. However, that shouldn't be the top item on a list for any developer position and it doesn't really mesh with "hacking code for pleasure". My guess: _cutting_ was considered a synonym for _hacking_ (Google Translate maybe?) and _a big surprise for many_ is just meant to be ironic.

Comment: @eric, the whole thing is odd to say the least. If it is writing code then what is the difference between that and "Core Software Development"? The whole thing sounds more like a frat house than a business.

Comment: cutting is used here in the sense of producing.

Comment: @user1220 established proably means they have funding and not just 50k from daddy/savings

Comment: I would not want to buy any finacial products from people who think like this. really financial stuff is complex and often has legal implications, I would like adults to be writing it not folks looking for a  fun job using toys.

Comment: "The environment is that of Facebook or Google..." - Is it commonplace to refer to other competitors to appeal to potential candidates? It just looks odd to me.

Comment: A slight mitigation of the use of `boys` is that they use it in `boys toys` (omitting the apostrophe on `boys’`, which gets a big negative mark from me), thus removing the insult by one degree. `Boys’ toys` is (alas) a fairly common phrase. But, if it riles you, don’t apply. I wouldn’t, as I deplore attempts to make `cutting code`, which simply means `coding`, by trying  (and failing) to sound hip . Also run away from phrases like `code-smith`, `code-jockey` and the like. They (and `boys’ toys`) tend to be a job smell)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The post is from a recruiter, and they chose their words poorly on multiple parts and in a variety of ways.

First of all, "cut code" is slang for "writing code" in the same way that some people refer to "cutting a check" (or "cheque" for the Brits). It is often considered a derisive term for a complex task, such as with [this top Google search result](http://linuxmednews.com/1173061242). Basically it reduces the work of a software engineer to being comparable to cutting a vegetable. A chef might be similarly insulted if they were told their job was food slicing, or for that matter telling a Certified Public Accountant that their job is cutting checks.

I'll also add that this ad is supposedly by a HR recruiting professional who should know better, and yet referred to technology as "boys toys". Maybe the author didn't intend sexist sentiment, but a professional should know better than to indicate gender for a job that doesn't specifically require it - and if it does require/prefer it on part of the company, that casts the employer in a very bad light indeed.

They intended to say - I HOPE - that the job involves actually writing new code and developing solutions, working with cool cutting edge technologies (I know it says it's heavily a Java position and most of the tech is old Java enterprise stuff: can't blame a salesman for trying to sizzle things up a bit, I suppose, though they really probably shouldn't in this case - if you know Java you know what it's reputation is).

Also, the last section is terribly worded, where strict requirements are mixed in with descriptions of the ideal candidate.

If I was the writers boss, I'd give them some heavy coaching and instruction. If I was the company who hired the recruiter, I'd just fire them.

Comment: I've never heard the phrase used, but I'm assuming it's referring to "cutting" as in "cutting a new trail" or "cutting a path through the woods".  The creative aspect of programming.  Still not a term I'll ever use, due to the multiple uses of the word "cut" in IT.

Comment: "Cheque" is the correct way ;-)

Comment: I thought at first it meant "cut back on code", like "budget cuts". But I think your explanation is more likely.

Comment: I think it's actually the opposite, removing (old, bad) code from the codebase.

Comment: @Kevin no its not

Comment: @Pepone why do you say that, especially with such certainty? Did you write the ad? Do you think it's a big surprise that a coder creates code?

Comment: @Kevin because I have been working in the it industry for over 3 decades your suggested meaning is not what this means at all

Comment: *points up* And this, ladies and gentlemen, is why the term is so horrible and should not be used. :)

Comment: @Pepone, I have also been in software engineering or following software engineering for nearly 2 decades, and I'm not sure what they are trying to imply, the surprise could be refactoring and reducing a code base, otherwise the "big surprise" statement is strange/out of place...

Comment: @Pepone I can play "Mary Had a Little Lamb" for 50 years every day on the piano for an hour but that would not make me a particularly great pianist. The fact you've been in the industry for a long time does not mean you're always aware of the newest terminology. "Cutting Code" _definitely_ means "negative code" here as in converting a large (usually inefficient) code base into a smaller better structured one. I've seen this term used at least 10 times before in blog posts. What daaxix said is also correct - if it's just writing code then it wouldn't be a "big surprise".

Comment: @daaxix You've been in software engineering for nearly two decades? So you started after 1995? Then [Here's a Nickel, Kid.](http://tomayko.com/writings/that-dilbert-cartoon) Seriously, "cutting code" means writing lines of code.

Comment: Australian here.  Yes, "cutting code" means writing code, nothing more, nothing less, and is not intended as pejorative.

Comment: To everyone wondering why "developer writing code" should be a big surprise - where did your sense of sarcasm go? This is another reason why everyone should just ignore this job ad and avoid that employer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum and daaxii but neither of you work in the UK which is where the job add is

Comment: @ChrisW, yes I started writing rasterizing game code in x86 assembler in high school, then learned C and C++ and wrote a bunch of low level graphics stuff.  I even wrote a little 2-d game that you could play over the serial port against someone else, in assembly (the game design wasn't good, just pixels chasing eachother like in a game of tag using the arrow keys on the keyboard).  Then in college I continued reading, learning, etc...and yet my circle of friends and colleagues never used that term, it goes to show that there are subcultures which may never cross...

Comment: @HorusKol, I suppose sarcasm does jive with the rest of the "brogrammer" sentiment in the ad...just not used to seeing irony and sarcasm in job ads, guess I'm getting old...

Comment: "Basically it reduces the work of a software engineer to being comparable to cutting a vegetable" - or cutting a diamond?  (it still just means coding, though)

Answer (score 16):

Maybe they mean [negative code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103807/what-is-negative-code)? The idea would be that removing unnecessary lines of code (cutting code) is just as important as writing code.

Poor choice of words though if that is the intent.

Comment: I agree, this is most likely. I know I always enjoy those +100/-1000 commits.

Comment: Agreed, this is more likely what I get from the posting. To simplify and refactor, reducing the code base while retaining functionality.

Comment: This is definitely what it means if it's anything like other postings I've seen.

Comment: no it not can non native speakers please refrain from inventing what you think an English word means - this answer just makes stack overflow look amateur

Comment: @Pepone +1 - this is not what it means and it is not likely that a job description would include "removing code" as opposed to just "writing code"

Comment: @AlexG I guess it would be a *big surprise to many* if that was the case, eh?

Comment: @JMK it's clearly sarcasm, a developer's job is primarily writing code (that alone should be a massive clue as to the real meaning of the phrase)

Comment: @Pepone exactly, the Americans are telling The Brits what it means?!

Answer (score 10):

I have a different background (coming from audio/video production and broadcasting, originally), and to me "Cut code" sounds like they're trying to borrow a phrase from the music recording industry, "Cut a track," which was jargon/slang for a recording session.  I took it to mean that the position actually writes code.  The fact that readers' backgrounds changes the impression of the post so dramatically goes to show how important it is to eliminate slang and euphemisms in written communication.

However, the jocular and sexist nature of the rest of the post makes this seem like it came from a bunch of immature frat boys (Male college fraternity members, for our international members), and @HLGEM pretty much covered that in her comment.

Besides, when being misogynistic, they should really have their grammar correct.  It should be: "... (boys' toys)."

I wouldn't even respond to this advertisement.

Comment: uh, it should really be *boyz toyz*

Comment: Cutting code is a slangy term for writing code with the implication that its new code not maintenance work I suspect this is a uk term. though the jargon file has cut a tape meaning to ship code

Comment: On my first read, it sounded like a young female HR rep wrote it who was trying to appeal to the "boys" she figured were the main brunt of coders.  I rarely hear males refer to their stuff as toys at all, let alone "boy's toys."

Comment: @Namfuak, yeah it is pretty much insulting to both women and men.

Comment: "Cut a track" - or a diamond?

Comment: This is the right answer - along the same lines as my assumption, that it comes from a similar notion to the [cutting room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_room_floor) - where a *cut* is produced, that is to say, a film is assembled from recorded footage and the wastage is eliminated.

Answer (score 6):

### What does it mean to "cut code"? And why would that be a big surprise?

'Cutting' code is old-fashioned slang for 'writing' code.

Very old-fashioned... here's a corresponding entry in the Jargon File:

> [cut a tape:
>   vi](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/C/cut-a-tape.html)
>
> To write a software or document distribution on magnetic tape for
>   shipment. Has nothing to do with physically cutting the medium! Early
>   versions of this lexicon claimed that one never analogously speaks of
>   ‘cutting a disk’, but this has since been reported as live usage.
>   Related slang usages are mainstream business's ‘cut a check’, the
>   recording industry's ‘cut a record’, and the military's ‘cut an
>   order’.
>
> All of these usages reflect physical processes in obsolete recording
>   and duplication technologies. The first stage in manufacturing an
>   old-style vinyl record involved cutting grooves in a stamping die with
>   a precision lathe. More mundanely, the dominant technology for mass
>   duplication of paper documents in pre-photocopying days involved
>   “cutting a stencil”, punching away portions of the wax overlay on a
>   silk screen. More directly, paper tape with holes punched in it was an
>   important early storage medium. See also burn a CD.

### Edit: as I can read from the comments, it looks like being quite a negative term, so why would they employ it in a job offer?

Writing lines-of-code is seen (by some) as a drudge job for junior programmers. According to SOME people, "seniors" don't do that: they do release management, product management, customer management, project management... anything except write code.

If (or because) the job requires coding as perhaps its main or *sine qua non* activity, I suppose they feel they must say so explicitly in the job offer: to try to weed out people who aren't willing and/or able to.

And reading the rest of the ad it's not really a big surprise at all.

Saying "big surprise" is meant to be 'ironic' or something. They have to say "writing code" (because it's the main requirement). They're embarrassed to say it, or trying to say it as if it's cool. So they're adding that statement as a kind of "inside joke" (i.e. "you and me, we know about coding: unlike MANY, to whom the need for CODING may come as a BIG SURPRISE").

Comment: "Seniors... [do] anything except write code." To the contrary, there are many senior coding positions in many organizations. Yes, seniors are expected to have additional skills, such as designing and implementing more complex components, but many seniors often still write code.

Comment: Yes, that's why I put "seniors" in "air quotes": I have, I kid you not, occasionally met that attitude. Apparently some people (i.e. people for whom coding as a job requirement might be a big surprise) are "too senior" for such drudgery.

Comment: Oh! I didn't catch the sarcasm when I originally read it :-)

Answer (score 4):

My guess as a developer is that they mean they want you to refactor code. This means that you'll be rewriting existing code. The code they have probably has a lot of technical debt (ie sloppily written, not well thought-out or no longer suitable for business needs) and they want you to clean it up. Not a fun job but pretty common in all honesty.

Comment: Nope, as has been pointed out repeatedly, it just means coding (in a rather pathetic, "ain't we hip?" sort of way)